# Error 440: Method 'Create' of object 'PivotCaches' failed

Tags: vba, excel, pivot, pivot-table

I have been trying to create a macro that populates a pivot table. However, I keep getting this

> Run-Time Error 440

on the `Set Cache` line.

Previously, I was running into other run time errors but those were easy fixes. I do not understand why the `PivotCaches.Create` method is not allowed in this case. SOS, please help!

Here is the code:

```
' Declare variables for pivots
Dim pivotWB As Workbook
Dim RawDataWS As Worksheet
Dim dataLocation As Range
Dim cache As PivotCache
Dim table As PivotTables

' name and set the workbook for pivot tables
folderName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(5, 13).Value
fileName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(6, 13).Value
extName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(7, 13).Value
wbAddress = folderName & "\" & fileName & "." & extName
Set pivotWB = Workbooks.Open(wbAddress)

Set dataLocation = pivotWB.Sheets("Raw Data").Range("A:AK")

Set cache = pivotWB.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase,_
sourceData:=dataLocation, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)

For i = 1 To 5

' create new worksheet and pivot table
pivotWB.Sheets.Add Before:=Sheets(1)
pivotWB.Sheets(1).Name = Left(toPivot(i), 30)
cache.CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=pivotWB.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1), TableName:=toPivot(i) & " Pivot Table"

' set rows
With pivotWB.Sheets(1).PivotTables(toPivot(i) & " Pivot Table").PivotFields("Rejection Category Description")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With

' set columns
With pivotWB.Sheets(1).PivotTables(toPivot(i) & " Pivot Table").PivotFields("Post Period")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
End With

' set values
With pivotWB.Sheets(1).PivotTables(toPivot(i) & " Pivot Table").PivotFields("Procedure Code")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 1
    .Function = xlCount
    .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
    .Name = "Count of Code"
End With
With pivotWB.Sheets(1).PivotTables(toPivot(i) & " Pivot Table").PivotFields("Amount")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 2
    .Function = xlSum
    .NumberFormat = "$#,##0"
    .Name = "Sum of Amount"
End With

Next i
```

Comment: Don't use entire columns for the source data, and do use the *address* of the range, in R1C1 format, rather than a range object. It's far more reliable.

Comment: Thank you Rory, this worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Rory comment, you need to set the `PivotCache` object using the `Address` property.

Also, setting your `table` object to your `PivotTable` will create a much easier and shorter code.

See code below, more notes inside the code's comments.

***Modified Code***

```
' --- set the Pivot Cache ---
Set cache = pivotWB.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
            SourceData:=dataLocation.Address(False, False, xlR1C1, xlExternal))

For i = 1 To 5
    ' create new worksheet and pivot table
    pivotWB.Sheets.Add Before:=Sheets(1)
    pivotWB.Sheets(1).Name = Left(toPivot(i), 30)

    ' --- set the Pivot-Table Object ---
    Set table = cache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=pivotWB.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1), TableName:=toPivot(i) & " Pivot Table")

    With table ' <-- after you set the table object, you can simply use With statement now

        ' set rows
        With .PivotFields("Rejection Category Description")
            .Orientation = xlRowField
            .Position = 1
        End With

        ' set columns
        With .PivotFields("Post Period")
            .Orientation = xlColumnField
            .Position = 1
        End With

        ' set values
        With .PivotFields("Procedure Code")
            .Orientation = xlDataField
            .Position = 1
            .Function = xlCount
            .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
            .Name = "Count of Code"
        End With
        With .PivotFields("Amount")
            .Orientation = xlDataField
            .Position = 2
            .Function = xlSum
            .NumberFormat = "$#,##0"
            .Name = "Sum of Amount"
        End With
    End With
Next i
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful!