# Issue creating Pivot Table using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've been wanting to create a pivot table off of a sheet called "Data". I worked on the code at first and everything worked out, but for some reason I now get the following error:

> Run-time error '440' Method 'Create" of object 'PivotCaches' failed

Here's my code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsData As Worksheet, wsPT As Worksheet

Sub Create_Pivot_Table()
Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long
Dim DataRange As range
Dim PTCache As PivotCache
Dim PT As PivotTable

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

Call Delete_PT_Sheet

With wsData
LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set DataRange = .range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))

Set wsPT = wb.Worksheets.Add
wsPT.Name = "Pivot Table"

Set PTCache = wb.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, DataRange)

Set PT = PTCache.CreatePivotTable(wsPT.range("B5"), "PIVOT")
With PT

'// Pivot Table Layout Settings
.RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow
.ColumnGrand = False
.RowGrand = False
.HasAutoFormat = False

'//Row Section (Layer 1)
With .PivotFields("Helper")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
    .LayoutBlankLine = False
End With

'// Values Section
With .PivotFields("Quantity")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Position = 1
    .Function = xlSum
    .NumberFormat = "#,##;(#,##);-"
End With

End With
End With

wsPT.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit


'//Releasing object memories
Set PTCache = Nothing
Set wsPT = Nothing
Set DataRange = Nothing
Set wsData = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub Delete_PT_Sheet()

On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wb.Worksheets("Pivot Table").Delete

End Sub
```

Could someone review the code and help me to fix it?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51895146/error-440-method-create-of-object-pivotcaches-failed

Comment: Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotcaches.create#:~:text=When%20passing%20a%20Range%20object%2C%20we%20recommend%20that%20you%20either%20use%20a%20string%20to%20specify%20the%20workbook%2C%20worksheet%2C%20and%20cell%20range%2C%20or%20set%20up%20a%20named%20range%20and%20pass%20the%20name%20as%20a%20string.%20Passing%20a%20Range%20object%20may%20cause%20%22type%20mismatch%22%20errors%20unexpectedly.